# Eclipse-Android-SDK: DDMS: File-Explorer doesn't open folder

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I would like to open a folder using the file explorer of DDMS, but when i try to expand that folder so that I could see its content nothing happens.
The folder is the `data` directory of my Padfone(not rooted) and looks like this:
[image: the data folder]

Has somebody an idea how to make this work?

Comment: is it a rooted device?

Comment: Are you creating any database? did you find your package name in that...? is your devices is rooted?

Comment: Why should I root my device? Is it not enough just to enable developer-settings?
@Sandip Armal Patil: What do you mean with database? Actually I create a file to save some data from my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Only for rooted device)
You must edit permission of data folder.

1. Root your device.
2. then go to " http://www.appsapk.com/root-explorer "  download & install in your device.
3. open the app, then On top select "Monunted as r/w"
4. then press over data folder (long click) and find Permission option

Have a somenthing like that
        read    write  execute
User

Group

Others

Make sure that "Others" have a check for read.
Do it for all the folders you want to access...

Then go to Eclipse and try again.

I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

The developer settings is just to get the phone detected by the adb so that you can debug your applications. Just because you did that doesn't mean that you can access all the folders in the phone. You will need to root your phone if you need to access the data/data folder in the DDMS. Or you could try to do this if you don't want to root the phone:

If the application is debuggable you can use the `run-as` command in adb shell

```
adb shell
run-as com.your.packagename` 
cp /data/data/com.your.pacakagename/
```

You can use Android's backup function.

```
adb backup -noapk com.your.packagename
```

You will now be prompted to 'unlock your device and confirm the backup operation'. It's best NOT to provide a password, otherwise it becomes more difficult to read the data. Just click on 'backup my data'. The resulting 'backup.ab' file on your computer contains all application data in android backup format. Basically it's a compressed tar file. [This](http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html) page explains how you can use OpenSSL's zlib command to uncompress it. You can use the adb restore backup.db command to restore the backup.

Comment: But why can I open a lot of the other folders, but not 'data'? Does it require special privileges?

Comment: As far as i know it is because of some rights management that are imposed by the OS for security reasons. And dont forget to accept and close the question if it helped you. Cheers